# LT1028 Vos trim value

Tags: amplifier

I am using LT1028 in simulation from the datasheet shown below. Pin 1 and 8 are Vos TRIM.

Regarding Vos:

Vos is input offset voltage. In my LTSPICE simulation I didn't have in the model, I only had input output and zero. The input offset voltage (VOS) is defined as the voltage that must be applied between the two input terminals of the op amp to obtain zero volts at the output. By the  datasheet below, how do I know what value I should use?

https://www.digikey.co.il/en/products/detail/analog-devices-inc/LT1028CS8-TRPBF/959596

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1028fd.pdf

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Real LT1028s will have some unknown Vos between +/-150uV (likely considerably less near room temperature and with luck). They may  have baked some fixed Vos into your simulation. You can figure that out, either by examining the model or by simulating it in a circuit. If they have simulated the Vos trim (if!) you can null out the Vos by a simulated 1kΩ pot connected as shown in the datasheet and adjusted to the correct setting. You would have to fiddle about to find the correct setting most likely.

Comment: Hello Sperhro, i am confused regarding the exact  \ impelentation of the 1K pot. as shown in the data sheet link below.
a potentiometer is a 3 leg device , the middle leg connected with one of the the legs is a variable resistor controlled by the viper.
1.What will happen if i connect +15 on the free leg in the device?
2.here will be a voltage divider between 15 and what other voltage?
3.how do i start adjusting the VOS? shown i put 0V at fitst between the two legs connected to the chip? or 15V?
I cant see how exact i should adjust it.
https://ibb.co/t2hnBN2

Comment: @lub2354 Please take a moment to review the edits. You've posted a number of questions now and should know how to make your questions more easily read. You always fail to capitalize "I" and always spell "below" incorrectly. Improving your communication improves the reception your questions get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simulate a 1kΩ pot you can use two resistors which add up to 1000Ω. If your simulation program has a pot in the library you can use that, typically it will have a value and a setting (call it \$\alpha\$ that can be set from 0 to 1 with 0.5 corresponding to the wiper in the middle). All that does is create one resistor of value \$R\cdot \alpha\$ and another \$R\cdot (1-\alpha)\$ connected to the wiper.

You can do this manually or parameterize the resistors.

Then, one approach would be to power the op-amp in the simulation and adjust the resistors until the output is very close to switching with both inputs grounded and the appropriate bipolar supply applied. If you apply a small (maybe a few uV) AC signal to the input it might be easier to do it by trial and error.

For what it's worth, the LT1028 model I have in my installation of LTspice has no Vos pins and the model does not have any input offset voltage.

Here are the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1028fd.pdf) pot connections. Note that the range of the pot adjustment is very large compared to the worst-case Vos of the op-amp (almost 10x) so the pot will be fairly touchy and drift-prone. It's not all that common to use the Vos adjust pins these days, so in real circuits you'll typically find those pins left open.

[image]

Comment: Hello Spehro,In this data sheet i also have the OVER_COMP leg which controls the gain bandwidth product.does it have use these days too? If i dont want to use it should i let it float too?Thanks.

Comment: Yes, leave it open. It might have use but it's not part of the model I have. There might be a more comprehensive model out there somewhere. If you're laying out a PCB it would not be amiss to provide for a capacitor between that terminal and the output in case it is required.